# A few issue with Settings

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to put in my app a SettingActivity for set up some **numerical** data (timeouts for http requests).

I created this xml file into res --> xml

**prefs.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<PreferenceCategory
    android:summary="Timeouts for  the HTTP requests"
    android:title="Timeouts">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="track_connection_timeout"
        android:title="Track connection timeout"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:defaultValue="10000"/>
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="track_download_timeout"
        android:title="Track download timeout"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:defaultValue="20000"/>
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="elevation_connection_timeout"
        android:title="Elevation connection timeout"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:defaultValue="10000"/>
     <EditTextPreference
         android:key="elevation_download_timeout"
         android:title="Elevation download timeout"
         android:inputType="number"
         android:digits="0123456789"
         android:defaultValue="10000"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

As you can see i'm trying to put **only** numbers into the EditTexts (without success).

I created this two classes too:

**SettingsActivity**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
    }
}
```

**SettingsFragment**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
}
```

In the MainActivity i have this:

```
private int trackConnectionTimeout;
private int trackDataTimeout;
private int elevationConnectionTimeout;
private int elevationDataTimeout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ....

    //Caricamento delle preferenze
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(MainActivity.this, R.xml.prefs, false);
    loadPreferences();

    ...
}

private void loadPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.
            getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    trackConnectionTimeout = Integer.parseInt(sp.getString("track_connection_timeout",null));
    trackDataTimeout   = Integer.parseInt(sp.getString("track_download_timeout",null));
    elevationConnectionTimeout =     Integer.parseInt(sp.getString("elevation_connection_timeout",null));
    elevationDataTimeout   = Integer.parseInt(sp.getString("elevation_download_timeout",null));
}
```

The issues are two:

1) This solution it's ok for API 11 or greater. I wish it could be compatible with all versions.

2) When the app starts i get: "NumberFormatException" because it isn't possible converts a null value to int value, but i set the default values!

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I repeate:

If i go in the settings and i cancel the content of an EditText, at the start of the app i get: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "". Accordingly the other values are not initialized.

For example i decide to cancel the content of the EditTextPreference that contains the value trackConnectionTimeout.

I close the application and i reopen it --> I get this:

04-15 17:54:46.867 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138) 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359) 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332) 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at com.loris.stefano.easyroutes.main.MainActivity.loadPreferences(MainActivity.java:235) 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at com.loris.stefano.easyroutes.main.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:431) 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184) 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5082) 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2586) 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2624) 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1249) 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787) 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-15 17:54:46.877 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-15 17:54:46.887 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 04-15 17:54:46.887 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 04-15 17:54:46.887 10999-10999/com.loris.stefano.easyroutes W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I can catch this Exception but the other values remains "null".

Comment: Regarding issue #1: Which part of your code only suits API 11+ ?

Answer (score 0):

For issue #2:

Change your code from

```
private int trackConnectionTimeout;
private int trackDataTimeout;
private int elevationConnectionTimeout;
private int elevationDataTimeout;
```

to

```
private Integer trackConnectionTimeout;
private Integer trackDataTimeout;
private Integer elevationConnectionTimeout;
private Integer elevationDataTimeout;
```

Integer, in difference to int, is an Object. Because of that it can be null.

See this link for more information:
[int vs Integer : Java Glossary](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/intvsinteger.html)

Comment: Not works. Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this.

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
trackConnectionTimeout = Integer.parseInt(sp.getString("track_connection_timeout","0"));
trackDataTimeout   = Integer.parseInt(sp.getString("track_download_timeout","0"));
elevationConnectionTimeout =     Integer.parseInt(sp.getString("elevation_connection_timeout","0"));
elevationDataTimeout   = Integer.parseInt(sp.getString("elevation_download_timeout","0"));
```

Now you never get a NumberFormatException.Just **Toast** or **Print** returned results to know that it retrieves the result correctly or only prints zero.And let me know anything else.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: This happens if i delete the contents of the EditText

Comment: EditText you mean the EditText Control.Then just put the code of your onTextChanged method.

Comment: I added a try/catch block for capture the exception. It seems to work.

Comment: I have no "onTextChanged" method.

Comment: Please be more specific.By showing LogCat output also.So the error can be identified more clearly.

Comment: If you put a try catch block.Then just put a Exception e in catch like catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); } then just put your exception detail be copying from the logcat output.

Comment: If i go in the settings and i cancel the content of an EditText, at the start of the app i get: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "". Accordingly the other values are not initialized.

Comment: If you want to have you a better answer.You must want to CO Operate with us.Iam asking you to put the logcat exception.For better analysing.

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours to answer to my own question LOL

Comment: Yes you have to wait for ...Not for hours,days or months.Until you provide a better output asked by the person who answers.